# Enable/Disable button click event on jquery smart wizard control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [this](http://mstratman.github.com/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/) control, which is the version 3 of jquery smart wizard.

This is the code of smart wizard:

```
$('#wizard').smartWizard({transitionEffect:'slide'});
```

This are helper functions in javascript:

```
function disableNextButton(){
    var $actionBar = $('.actionBar');
    $('.buttonNext', $actionBar).addClass('buttonDisabled').off("click");
}

function enableNextButton(){
    var $actionBar = $('.actionBar');
    $('.buttonNext', $actionBar).removeClass('buttonDisabled');
}
```

The css class actionBar, is used to style the area where are placed previous, next and finish buttons. The style buttonNext is applied to next button and the style buttonDisabled is used to put gray color to a button. All the referred styles are contained in smart wizard css files.

The problem is that I can disable button click event using ".off" function of jquery, but I cannot restore the original event handler with ".on".

My question is how do I restore next button click event after disabling button?

Thanks.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: i guess you'd have better to use delegation and filter it by class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reading the code of jquery smartwizard, I've decided to do the following for enableNextButton function:

```
function enableNextButton($wiz){
    var $actionBar = $('.actionBar');
    $('.buttonNext', $actionBar).removeClass('buttonDisabled')
            .bind('click', function() {
                $wiz.smartWizard('goForward');
                return false;
            });
}
```

The jquery wizard object is passed as a parameter.

This solves the problem of restoring click functionality, although repeating code from smart wizard.

Answer (score 0):

.off unlinks the event handler, so you need to re-attach the event handler. You can't just say

```
$('.buttonNext', $actionBar).removeClass('buttonDisabled').on("click");
```

because jQuery doesn't "remember" what the event was, or if you have more than one event, which event you wanted bound. You can use the click shorthand to specify the function like this:

```
$('.buttonNext', $actionBar).removeClass('buttonDisabled').click(function() {
  // Code for your click goes here.
});
```